# AHK Load hotstrings without using #Include Subroutines.ahk

Tags: autohotkey, filereader

I have a txt file named subroutines.ahk  in it is the below hotstring.

```
::btw::Thank you for the help
```

I know if I want to run my hotstring from another script all I have to do is include it in that script  using:

```
#include subroutines.ahk
```

But I dont want to do that Instead from another script I want to Loop read the  contents of subroutines.ahk  and load the hotstring variables  that way .

```
Loop, read,subroutines.ahk
{
  Loop, parse, A_LoopReadLine, %A_Tab%
{
    MsgBox, Field number %A_Index% is %A_LoopField%.
}
}
```

I would really appreciate  your help on how I can load my hotstring variables into another script that way.

I plan to encode  the hotsrings in  subroutines.ahk   and than  decode the contents of the subroutines.ahk in the second program and load it into memory. 
In the above example though i am first trying to figure out how I can loop read the txt file and run the hot strings from there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Demonstrates the use of hotkeys that map to dynamic values

```
; Replace hash values with whatever method you use to decrypt your hotstrings
decrypted := {abc: "alpha", def: "beta"}

::abc::
  Send % decrypted["abc"]
  return
::def::
  Send % decrypted["def"]
  return
```

When you type "abc", "alpha" appears instead

Answer (score 1):

`#` directives are processed only once when the script is launched. To work around this limitation, you can use `reload` to execute dynamically generated script that includes `#` directives.

**Code sample:**

When F1 is pressed, use the contents of "subroutines.ahk" to generate and run code that utilizes `#` directives:

```
F1:: reload_hotstrings()

#Include temp.ahk

reload_hotstrings()
{
  FileDelete temp.ahk
  loop read, subroutines.ahk
  {
    MsgBox Hotstring number %A_Index% is %A_LoopReadLine%.
    FileAppend %A_LoopReadLine%`n, temp.ahk
  }
  reload
}
```

Alternatively, if you want to automatically generate hotkeys code whenever autohotkey starts:

*I'm using `source.dat` for your `subroutines.ahk` file*

**Code sample:**

```
FileGetTime source_time,   source.dat
FileGetTime compiled_time, compiled.ahk
; calculate time difference between source and compiled files
EnvSub source_time, %compiled_time%, Seconds

; compile and run if source newer
if source_time > 0
{
  FileDelete compiled.ahk
  loop read, source.dat
  {
    FileAppend %A_LoopReadLine%`n, compiled.ahk
  }
  reload
}

#Include compiled.ahk
```

Comment: This is good except it comes back to appending to #Include compiled.ahk and reloading it ... I'm trying to avoid that because I will  have a   source.dat that is encrypted  when i load source,dat  i will than decrypt it ...here lies the problem once i decrypt it I just want to load it and run , I dont want to save my decrypted content  on disk.

Comment: see my new answer which avoids saving decrypted content to disk.  I use a hash with string literals for the decrypted values, but you could programmatically decrypt the values from a data file